# SQL Group By with serial number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my table in SQL Server :

```
Customer_Code   Factor_Number    Factor_Sum
-------------------------------------------
100                10             24500
100                15             12550
102                14             1000
103                18             65500
103                12             1000
```

and I want this output in SQL Server without any temp table :

```
Customer_Code   Factor_Count    Factor_Sum   Factor_Number
----------------------------------------------------------
100                2              37050          10,15
102                1              1000           14
103                2              66500          12,18
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Seems like a pretty simple `GROUP BY` with a `SUM`, a `COUNT` and a `STRING_AGG` aggregates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `STRING_AGG()` in a `CTE`, then just `GROUP` after that.

```
drop table if exists #tmp
create table #tmp (customer_Code int, factor_number int, factor_sum int)

insert into #tmp 
Values 
(100,10,24500),
(100,15,12550),
(102,14,1000),
(103,18,65500),
(103,12,1000)

;with cte
as (
    select customer_Code,STRING_AGG(factor_number,',') as factor_number
    from #tmp
    group by customer_Code)

select t.customer_Code,count(*) as Factor_Count, sum(factor_sum) as factor_sum, c.factor_number
from #tmp t
join cte c on t.customer_Code=c.customer_Code
group by t.customer_Code, c.factor_number
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like aggregation:

```
select customer_code,
       count(*) as factor_count,
       sum(factor_sum) as factor_sum,
       string_agg(factor_number, ',') within group (order by factor_number) as factor_numbers
from t
group by customer_code;
```

If you only have at most two rows per customer, then you don't even need `string_agg()`:

```
select customer_code,
       count(*) as factor_count,
       sum(factor_sum) as factor_sum,
       concat_ws(',', min(factor_number), nullif(max(factor_number), min(factor_number)))
from t
group by customer_code;
```